# In Javascript, is adding a variable to a function considered acceptable?

Tags: javascript

I've been experimenting with JavaScript, and noticed I can add attributes to a functions like this...

```
// a library function
function someLibrary(num) {
  var obj = {};
  obj.times = someLibrary.times(num);
  return obj;
};

// add 'times' function to library
someLibrary.times = function(num){
  return function(func) {
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i += 1) {
      func(i);
    };
  };
};

// prints 0 through 4
someLibrary(5).times(function(i){
  console.log(i);
});
```

Is there anything wrong with saying `someLibrary.times = function(){}`?  I haven't seen any articles talk about writing code this way.

Comment: There is a very popular library that does this. It's called jQuery.

Comment: Normally *someLibrary* would be a plain object and is used simply as a "namespace" for the library. Having it as a function isn't "wrong", but you need to think carefully about the semantics of what calling *someLibrary* should do.

Comment: @FelixKling—yes, but jQuery loves overloading things so having the base reference be both a function and "namespace" is not surprising. I doubt that someone would *not* use it for that feature alone, but if they did, there are plenty of alternatives (and plenty of others that do it too).

Comment: @FelixKling jQuery does not augment other libraries’ functions, or does it?

Comment: @Pumbaa80: no, but it adds properties to a function.

Comment: That's right. `$` itself is a function after all.

Comment: ECMAScript itself does it, e.g. `Object.keys()`, `String.fromCharCode()`, `Number.MAX_VALUE`, etc.

Comment: @RobG thanks for pointing that out.  What I'm learning here is that if you're the one who writes the language or library, you can decide for yourself what the rules should be.  My main concern was primarily trying to figure out if ```someLibrary.times = function(){}``` was somehow going to get me in trouble with the language itself.  I'm new to "real" JavaScript programming, and JS has all sorts of weird gotchas.

Comment: @amorphid—remember that there is the language, [*ECMAScript*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), and various implementations such as JavaScript, JScript, etc. DOM objects aren't functions, you can't do `document()` or `window()`. To create instances you call a method like `var newWindow = window.open(...)` or `var newDocument = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing "wrong" with it from a technical standpoint, but there is absolutely no reason to do so. That library might define it's own function `times` at some point in the future, and now you're stuck with a codebase that cannot be upgraded to the newer version of the library without rewriting your own `times` function.

Comment: Maybe it'd be more clear if I'd called it ```myLibrary```.  Would you give the same answer if I were writing the library for my own purposes?  I'm not trying to append the `.times` function to someone else's code.

Comment: Then the first sentence still stands. Unless you're explicitly extending the library with related functionality, there's no reason to add arbitrary functions to it. If you *are* adding functionality to the library, there is nothing wrong with doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a function is an object, so you can attach properties to it. Just because you can doesn't mean you should though.

Comment: I just took a look at Underscore.js, and this command works => ```_(5).times(function(i) { console.log(i); });```.  It looks like `_` returns a function, and ```_(5).times ``` returns a function.  I'll have to look at the source code and see how they do it.  I'll report back once I've dug into it.

Comment: @amorphid nope, `_` returns an object: `typeof _(5) != 'function'`

Comment: There are some cases where it can be useful (the typical example is a counter to generate unique IDs). It can make the code very messy though.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 you are correct.  I was saying that ```_``` returns a function.  By making ```someLibrary``` a function, I can type in the command ```someLibrary(someVar)```, as a opposed to ```someLibrary.someFunction(someBar)```.  A framework like Ember uses an object at the top level, which means you can't type in ```Ember()```.

Comment: Let's be very clear here. `_` **is** a function that **returns** an object. That is a huge difference.